# Images are Downloading as Blank with No size

Tags: python, python-3.x, image, beautifulsoup, error-handling

Hi so i have successfully web scraped sketchers website, and have got all image links, but when i download them, Most of them download as blank. any help please :)

My Code:

```
import pandas as pd
import requests

Finalv1 = pd.read_excel("Boots1.xlsx")
Finalv1.index+=1

a = Finalv1.index.tolist()
Name = Finalv1["Title"].tolist()
Images = Finalv1["Images"].tolist()

s = requests.Session()

for i,n,l in zip(a,Name,Images):
    r = s.get(l).content
    with open ("Images//" + f"{i}-{n}.jpg","wb") as f:
        f.write(r)
```

My output: [output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QzRFY.png)

My excel file for reference (Google Drive LInk): [Excel File](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1aKojc5DToILvbjJqBrBxgiDkj-AirMZw/view?usp=sharing)

Answer (score 0):

A potential fix, would be to use the requests content to add a proper file extension.

Here's how:

```py
import pandas as pd
import requests

them_boots = pd.read_csv("boots.csv")
them_names = them_boots["Title"].to_list()
them_links = them_boots["Images"].to_list()

with requests.Session() as connection:
    for boot in zip(them_names, them_links):
        name, image_source = boot
        content = connection.get(image_source)
        extension = content.headers["Content-Type"].split("/")[-1]
        print(f"Walk a mile in {name}")
        with open(
                f"{'_'.join(name.split()).replace(':', '')}.{extension}",
                "wb",
        ) as image:
            image.write(content.content)
```

Output:

[image]

Or in a more detailed way:

```
Alley_Cats_-_Talgen.jpeg -> 15.3 KB
Cascades.jpeg -> 17.6 KB
Cascades_-_Talsen.jpeg -> 15.4 KB
Ithaca_-_Beaufort.jpeg -> 17.2 KB
Ithaca_-_Stowe.jpeg -> 15.5 KB
Ithaca_-_Swiftwater.jpeg -> 18.7 KB
Ithaca_-_York.jpeg -> 13.1 KB
Mariners.jpeg -> 18.3 KB
Mariners_-_Pilot.jpeg -> 11.4 KB
Parallux_-_Ando.jpeg -> 15.9 KB
Relaxed_Fit:_Folsten_-_Doramo.jpeg -> 17.8 KB
Relaxed_Fit:_Marcelo_-_Topel.jpeg -> 20 KB
Relaxed_Fit:_Molton_-_Gaveno.jpeg -> 12.1 KB
Relaxed_Fit:_Polano_-_Norwood.jpeg -> 19.1 KB
Relaxed_Fit:_Relment_-_Pelmo.jpeg -> 21.2 KB
Relaxed_Fit:_Relment_-_Traven.jpeg -> 19.3 KB
Relaxed_Fit:_Riglen_-_Lofield.jpeg -> 17.4 KB
Relaxed_Fit:_Segment_-_Ander.jpeg -> 18 KB
Relaxed_Fit:_Segment_-_Garnet.jpeg -> 13.4 KB
Relaxed_Fit:_Selmen_-_Relodge.jpeg -> 21.5 KB
Relaxed_Fit:_Sole_Trek_-_Mayock.jpeg -> 17.5 KB
Relaxed_Fit:_Trekson_-_Gleason.jpeg -> 22.3 KB
Relaxed_Fit:_Trekson_-_Grapel.jpeg -> 18.3 KB
Revine_-_Hopkin.jpeg -> 14.9 KB
Skechers_Arch_Fit_Phantom_-_Illusive.jpeg -> 17.7 KB
Verdict.jpeg -> 18.1 KB
Work:_Argum_-_Alkova_ST_WP.jpeg -> 18.5 KB
Work:_Argum_ST_WP.jpeg -> 16.2 KB
Work:_Blais_-_Bixford_ST.jpeg -> 22.5 KB
Work:_Burgin_-_Tarlac_ST.jpeg -> 21.2 KB
Work:_Delleker_-_Lakehead_ST.jpeg -> 19.7 KB
Work:_Moltke_WP.jpeg -> 10.7 KB
Work:_Monter_Comp_Toe.jpeg -> 20.6 KB
Work:_Pettus_-_Lebaum.jpeg -> 19 KB
Work:_Queznell_ST_WP.jpeg -> 21.3 KB
Work:_Relaxed_Fit_-_Workshire_ST.jpeg -> 13.5 KB
Work:_Robards_SR.jpeg -> 17.8 KB
Work:_Tapter_-_Gorle_ST.jpeg -> 14.1 KB
Work:_Trevok_ST_WP.jpeg -> 13.8 KB
Work:_Trophus_-_Letic_ST.jpeg -> 16.9 KB
Work:_Vicksburk_-_Fetor_ST.jpeg -> 15.3 KB
Work:_Vinten_-_Courtenay_WP_SR.jpeg -> 21.2 KB
Work:_Weirton_WP.jpeg -> 9.7 KB
Work_Relaxed_Fit:_Braly_Tactical.jpeg -> 16.1 KB
Work_Relaxed_Fit:_Burgin_-_Sosder_Comp_Toe.jpeg -> 21.8 KB
Work_Relaxed_Fit:_Holdredge_-_Rebem_ST.jpeg -> 20.9 KB
Work_Relaxed_Fit:_Kadmiel.jpeg -> 16.5 KB
Work_Relaxed_Fit:_Markan_Tactical.jpeg -> 16.3 KB
Work_Relaxed_Fit:_Pettus.jpeg -> 22.8 KB
Work_Relaxed_Fit:_Vicksburk_ST.jpeg -> 14.7 KB
Work_Relaxed_Fit:_Wascana_-_Athas_Tactical.jpeg -> 13.2 KB
Work_Relaxed_Fit:_Wascana_-_Benen_WP_Tactical.jpeg -> 17.1 KB
Work_Relaxed_Fit:_Wascana_-_Millit_WP.jpeg -> 18.2 KB
Work_Relaxed_Fit:_Workshire_-_Condor.jpeg -> 14 KB
Downloaded 54 files with total size of 930.6 KB
```

Comment: hi i tried you method, 16 images were downloaded but out of them 3 were 0 bytes or no images :(

Comment: I cannot reproduce that. The code downloads all 54 files and *none* of them is of 0 bytes in size. See the updated answer.

Comment: hi, so i finally solved it by removing the colon in the file name in excel. it was not showing any errors so i thought colons were allowed, but turns out they mess up the files in windows. :)

Comment: Here's a pro tip - don't use Windows.

Comment: Hahaha. Well in the future will upgrade to a better machine as well. Thanks for your help btw :)

Answer (score -2):

**hi, so i finally solved it by removing the colon in the file name in excel. it was not showing any errors so i thought colons were allowed, but turns out they mess up the files in windows. :)**